# How to install specific helm client version so it is compatible with the server (Tiller)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

My helm client and server are different versions. I need to update my client so it is same version as the server.

```
$ helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.15.2", GitCommit:"8dce272473e5f2a7bf58ce79bb5c3691db54c96b", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.16.3", GitCommit:"1ee0254c86d4ed6887327dabed7aa7da29d7eb0d", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

I tried to update via the installer script here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get

but when I do that, it will give me this message:

```
Downloading helm
Helm v2.16.3 is already v2.16.3
```

How to install specific helm client version so it is compatible with the server (Tiller)? In this case version 2.16.3.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the specific Helm version, you can follow [Helm: From the binary releases](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/). You can see and download all Helm client versions from [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases).

Btw. as a side note, I strongly suggest moving to Helm 3. There is no Tiller there, so you don't have to "sync" the versions between client and server.